# how to use IN-function within Zend_Select

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, zend-framework3

I different string values komma separated out of a form.

In the code I cast them and then it looks like this:

$kritkeyword ='test, abc, xyz';

Now I want to use the variable within an IN-function. In original sql ist would be:

```
where keyword IN ('test', 'abc', 'xyz')
```

In my code I tried to do the following:

```
$select->where('keyword IN (?)', $kritkeyword);
```

I also tried:

```
$select->where(['keyword IN ?' =>$kritkeyword]);
```

Until now I had different ideas how to write it, but I always get a sql error. So how to do this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use Zend\Db\Sql\Where. If `$kitkeyword` is array :

```
$condition = new Zend\Db\Sql\Where();
$condition->in('keyword', $kritkeyword);
$select->where($condition);
```

Comment: You can also you  $select->where->in('keyword', $kritkeyword); as zend then will behind the scene create a Zend\Db\Sql\Where Object

Comment: thats the same like Alain Pomirol suggested